# phusion passenger - deploying rails application - No such file or directory - config/environment.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am trying to deploy my Rails app on apache and for that am using phusion passenger.

I followed the modrails documentation but i seem to have missed something because am getting the following error message:

```
Error message:
    No such file or directory - config/environment.rb
Exception class:
    Errno::ENOENT
```

Here is my http.conf:-----

```
--------------------------------------------------
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName glen:80



DocumentRoot /opt/MAWWW/Public/html/
  RailsEnv test
  PassengerDefaultUser gin
  RailsBaseUri /rails


<Directory "/opt/MAWWW/Public/html/rails">
 Options -Multiviews
 AllowOverride all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I even created a soft link pointing to my RoR application's public folder:

```
ln -s /Sub_Interface/public /export/system0/MAWWW/Public/html/rails
```

Is there anything am doing incorrectly??

Thanks a lot for any suggestion provided

Comment: How are you deploying? Capistrano, git repository etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You should set your virtual host to the public directory of your Rails app.

Ex: if my project is `<My Sample Rails project>`

then

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName portal.localhost
      DocumentRoot /<full root to the directory>/<My Sample Rails project>/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Try that and re-start Apache.